# How does the Gordo Snare work?

Tags: slime-rancher

I fabricated a Novice Gordo Snare from the Lab and placed it down. Apparently, it’s supposed to lure gordos to where it is placed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must place a food item on the pad once placed and sleep until the next day.

Once you wake up, you should find a random slime that eats the food you gave. While with the Novice Gordo Snare you’ll mostly get a Pink Gordo, higher tiers of Gordo Snares will be less random by increasing the chances of giving you the Gordo that favors that food.

Comment: Why do you place a question and answer it within 3 min? You should let other people answer the question or don't make this question if you already know the answer. Only answer the question when there has been some time since the asking and you found the answer or just don't ask it.

Comment: @Wouter Answering your own question is perfectly okay, you can even post and answer a question at the same exact time. It's allowed and encouraged IF the question is good.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I did that once and even tho the question was upvoted I got called out for it for answering my own question because I didn't gave others the chance

Comment: @Wouter They were mistaken.